# Should i sanitize $_POST data if used in if statement?

Tags: php, post, sanitization, sanitize

i am implementing a simple closed area on a website.
The access is granted upon entering the right password. The password is shared so no real accounts are in place.
I am trying to understand if i am missing some variable filtering and if i should sanitize the data. I'm pretty sure i must do it, but i don't know what is the best approach.

In my code i have two places where i use the data from the $_POST variable:

```
if(isset($_POST)&&$_POST['the_password']!="")
{
    $my_password = $_POST['the_password'];
    //Should i use something like this?
    //$my_password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'the_password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
}
```

The second place is where i use the variable, in an if statement:

```
if($a_password == $my_password)
{
    //Query using the $a_password variable
}
```

In this part of code $a_password comes from a hard coded query.

Is the filter_input function the right one? Am i missing something?

Comment: sanitize it for what?

Comment: Since you do not seem to have much concern for security, sanitize is maybe overkill.

Comment: Compare SHA1($_POST["password"]) against `StoredSHA1Hash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no; for an `if` statement, your code is safe.

However, if you edit the code later, you should use prepared statements in you database queries.